# Mail sent from my website going to gmail spam folder when including a link

Tags: email, hyperlink, gmail, spam

Whenever i try to send a mail from my website for email verification, the same is being received in a spam folder. I noticed that plain messages are being received in inbox, but whenever i try to include an ordinary http link[http://abcd.in/abcd/verify.php?key=2f27feb552c83c6c65b9bfc4d799e775], the mail goes to the spam folder.  Cant point out the reason why this is happening. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, I know that the spam score can be affected when hyperlinks have an alphanumeric argument tagged onto the end. I suggest trying to reformat the URL into something like;

```
http://abcd.in/abcd/f27feb552c83c6c65b9bfc4d799e775/verify.php
```

and extracting the reference using a `Regex` or `Split(`)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i had to reduce the length of alphanumeric key from 32 to 16 characters. Now it works like charm :)

Comment: You really saved my life. I Was searching for this for more than 48 hrs. nice, clever and simple way. Thanks mate, +1.

Answer (score 0):

- Is your outgoing mail server configured to receive mail?
- Are you using a proper mail server with proper setup at all or some bulk-mail-sending dud?
- Are your mails sent with a real from address? And I don't mean the header-from that you can add in your software, but the protocol-from that is being used by sendmail
- Do you have domain keys/dkim set up for your mail server?
- Is the header OR the protocol from address from a different domain? Do they have set up domain keys allowing your mailserver?
- Does your mail server feature the same domain name on the reverse lookup?
- Does your mail server offer to receive mail for the user they are sending for?
- Is your webhost using a smart relay? Do they rewrite the from: address?
- Or do you send mails with internal mail address from?